# Is a barber a barber if he doesn't get paid?

Tags: logic, fallacies, paradox, semantics, bertrand-russell

For reference: The Barber Paradox.

> The Barber is he who shaves all those, and only those, who doesn't shave themselves.
>
> Now the question is: Who shaves the Barber?

The paradox being that if the Barber shaves himself he must be one of those who doesn't shave themselves, and if he does shave himself he cannot be one of those who the Barber shaves.

**So my question is: Is this really a paradox or simply a case of category error?**

Because a barber shaves people for payment, yet he would not pay himself when he shaves himself, so therefore when shaving himself he is not de facto "The Barber". The Barber is in fact primarily a person and secondarily (sometimes) The Barber.

Comment: The paradox mentions nothing about payment. Assume he works for free, there are also multiple ways to rephrase it so that such analogical distractions do not come up. Indeed, it was Russell's way of popularizing a purely mathematical paradox, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox).

Comment: I argue that "sets that do/don't include themselves" does not _exactly_ fit what's going on here. The paradox as stated is framed in natural language and as such are predicated on natural language definitions. And then a barber that does nothing but shave, and does so for free, or a shaving machine that also grows a beard, all seems very contrived... I understand there is a real problem with Cantor Set Theory, but Russel's solution to that is actually quite _similar_ to the solution above. But one arise from improper handling of sets and this paradox depends on the conflagration of categories

Comment: The barber is just a popular illustration, everything that natural language associations add to it is irrelevant. That cutting them off makes it contrived is fine as long as it can still serve the illustrative purpose. If natural associations suggest a solution that is nice, but solution is a separate issue from the statement. And Russell's solution did not involve introducing extraneous distinctions analogous to payment, that would not work for reformulations where payment makes no sense. It involved the [vicious circle principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicious_circle_principle).

Comment: I wouldn't call that a category mistake. You want to distinguish two senses of "shaving" (as a professional or personal activity, but both are from the same category: activities) and reframe the sentence as: the barber professionally shaves all and only those who don't personally shave themselves. So basically you do not solve the original paradox, you want us to focus on another problem which is not paradoxical.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant I was thinking more in terms of the category "barber", and when it applies i.e. the _person_ is only the barber when shaving those who do not shave themselves. At any rate the question is actually more about Russel's paradox in Set Theory, and whether the Barber Paradox is a good correlation to it. See Conifold's comments for that interpretation.

Comment: He's shaved by Occam's razor.

Comment: Presumably the Barber doesn't shave. Either that or the situation is impossible. I find it a poor scenario for exploring R's set-theoretic paradox since it doesn't seem to be a paradox.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Unless if the categories alluded to, in the question, were to correlate with R's "types".

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need to use the word "barber," or to assume any exchange of money in this case. It takes a bit of elementary set theory (logic alone doesn't seem to be enough), but it is easy to prove that **someone** living in the village can shave those an only those men living in a village who do not shave themselves if and only if that person is *not* a man [edit: e.g. that person could be a woman living there].  (Full details at my [blog posting](http://www.dcproof.com/BarberParadoxSets.htm).)

Comment: Or the barber could be a machine. For some other caveats see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox, And the exchanges between me and Conifold which also tells the real purpose of the Barber paradox: Illustrating contradictions in Cantor Set Theory.

Comment: @christo183 That would work if a machine could be a villager, maybe some kind of android? The biconditional in myproof only works for elements of the set of villagers V, who may or may not be men, i.e. elements of the subset M.